# import text file into one column and assign default value to other columns of mysql table

Tags: mysql, file, text, load

**Text file:**

```
American River College
American University
Amherst College
......
......
```

**Table Fields**

```
id
name
type
created_at
updated_at
```

I want to import text field values in **`name`** column and want to assign some default value to other fields like **"college"** to **`type`** field, **current date time** to **`created_at`**  and **NULL** to **`updated_at`** columns.

What changes i would need to make in the following command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/colleges.txt'
INTO TABLE selections
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I have seen various examples of stackoverflow.com but could not find matching with my specific requirement.

Comment: It is not INLINE, it is INFILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add SET statement at the end of your LOAD DATA INFILE.
For example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/colleges.txt'
INTO TABLE selections
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name)
SET updated_at=null, created_at=NOW(), type="college"
```

Comment: I tried above command, the only issue i faced that text file value is not being inserted. A blank value is inserted into the table..Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the lines terminated by \r\n ? Because it may be only \n for example. Line breaks on windows are different than on Linux. What OS are you on?

Comment: I changed it to \n but still blank is being inserted. Not able to figure out the issue

Comment: can you upload your file somewhere?

Comment: Any Luck with provided text file ?

Comment: I can see your line ending is \n. I think the main problem is that your first column is id, while you're trying to import a file which has first column the name. Try now (I've updated the answer so it loads the data into name column).